# PostgreSQL : CAST column only if exists

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, postgresql-9.5

OS Linux Debian 5.3.1 if that helps.

I have a bunch of CSV files that I managed to import as tables in PostgreSQL. They all have the same general layout (i.e. globally same columns), however some of them vary slightly (i.e. some of them may miss some columns). To be clearer, the general layout is supposed to be columns a, b, c, d, e, however some table only have colums a, b, d, e, other only columns b, c, d, e...

I'd like to make a general SQL query for changing the type of the columns (using CAST) and import them in one single global table (t_import) with columns a, b, c, d, e.

```
INSERT INTO t_import (a, b, c, d, e)
    SELECT (
      (CAST a AS integer) AS a,
      (CAST b AS character varying(14)) AS b,
      (CAST c AS integer) AS c,
      (CAST d AS character varying) AS d,
      (CAST e AS character varying) AS e
    FROM t_csv;
```

However as some tables miss some columns, I should be creating a query for each table I want to import, which would be too tiresome for the number of tables I have.

Is there a way to check if the column exists in the table I want to import, an only if it exists, CAST it, else use some default value ? This way would allow me to use the same query for my different tables without getting errors.

Globally this I what I'd like to do :

- check if colum exists in the table I want to import,
- if the column exists, CAST it in the type I want and use this for the INSERT INTO,
- if the column doesn't exist, use some default value so the INSERT INTO still has something to insert and I don't get an error message.

After many research I still haven't found the technical solution. I struggle with parameters like IF EXISTS, WHERE EXISTS, sub-queries... and can not manage to do this. Is there a way to do it or do I have the wrong way to look at this problem ?

Comment: You need a function that uses dynamic SQL and retrieves the columns from e.g. `information_schema.columns`

Answer (score 0):

Unite the `select` queries providing the defaults:

```
insert into t_import (a, b, c, d, e)

select
    a::integer,
    b::character varying(14),
    c::integer,
    d::character varying,
    e::character varying
from t_csv

union all

select
    null,
    a,
    null,
    b,
    c
from t2_csv
```

Notice that the columns will be passed to the `insert` command in the order they are selected regardless of their names and aliases.

From the second united table on the columns will be cast to their corresponding columns in the first select so it is not necessary to explicitly cast.